# Change textfield to double with button click

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to use a textfield to take a string and then when the save button is clicked, it saves that value typed as a double using CoreData. But it keeps giving an error stating that "Value of optional type 'Double?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Double'" Any ideas?

1. hoursSlept is the variable the textfield is bonded to
2. newSleep is the variable for the struct SleepModel (my sleep type)
3. Im taking the textfield value and trying to force into a double using Double() with a new variable. But it keeps giving the error.

```
Button(action: {
                  var hoursSleptDouble = Double(hoursSlept)
                  newSleep!.hoursSlept = hoursSleptDouble
                  
                  if newSleep != nil {
                      coreDataViewModel.saveRecord(sleepModel: newSleep!) {
                          print("Success")
                      }
                  }
              })
               {
                    Capsule()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                        .frame(height: 44)
                        .overlay(Text("Add Entry").foregroundColor(Color.white).bold())
                }.padding()
```

Comment: The answer is in the error message.  Initialising a Double with a string provides an optional Double (as the text might not represent a number).  You will need to unwrap this to a Double.

Comment: I unwrap it using the ! and then the app crashes stating the value is nil....?       Button(action: {
                  let hoursSleptDouble = Double(hoursSleptString)
                  newSleep.hoursSlept = hoursSleptDouble!
                  if newSleep != nil {
                      coreDataViewModel.saveRecord(sleepModel: newSleep) {
                          print("Success")
                      }
                  }
              })

Answer (score 0):

Based on someones advise I switched the code up a bit. I initialized the sleepModel inside of a function which is called when the button is pushed. Then inside that function I create the doubles from the user input textfields. That way there are no optionals!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).